# How align button to right in framework7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

Sorry for my elementary question, but I have spent a lot of time and I can't understand the mistake. I have a card and I'd like to show the button on the right inside the card footer. Now the button is displayed on the left.

Thank you in advance!

This is my HTML page where I have the card

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-100 tablet-auto desktop-auto">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content card-content-padding">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-100 tablet-auto desktop-80">
            <div class="list">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <!--<a class="item-link smart-select smart-select-init">-->
                  <a href="#" class="item-link smart-select smart-select-init" data-open-in="popup" data-virtual-list="fruits1" data-page-back-link-text="Indietro">
                    <select name="fruits1">
                      <option value="">apple</option>
                      <option value="">banana</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="item-content">
                      <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title">Fruits 1</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="item-link smart-select smart-select-init" data-open-in="popup" data-virtual-list="fruits2" data-page-back-link-text="Indietro">
                    <select name="fruits2"> </select>
                    <div class="item-content">
                      <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title">Fruits 2</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- ./ list -->
          </div>
          <!-- ./ block -->
        </div>
        <!--col-->
      </div>
      <!--row-->
    </div>
    <!--card-content-->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <div class="row justify-content-right">
        <div class="col text-align-right">
          <a class="button button-fill" href="#">Search</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--card-footer-->
  </div>
  <!--card-->
</div>
<!--col-->
```

Comment: please provide your css or make a fiddle and post the link here so that I can help you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve issue by distribute a footer to two section, one for left, and second one for right, or by custom style....

You can update your code by adding empty span before your button, then the card footer will display your button in right...

Look at this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rk0bcatw/1/).

```
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">Card header</div>
      <div class="card-content card-content-padding">Card with header and footer. Card headers are used to display card titles and footers for additional information or just for custom actions.</div>
      <div class="card-footer"><span></span><a class="button button-fill" href="#">Search</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome any time @fgg :)